# object doesn't support this property or method javascript error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm getting an "object doesn't support this property or method" error in IE 8. There's no error in firefox.

Anybody have an idea as to what's causing it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callReport() {
      var sPath = $('input[name*="ReportPath"]').val();
      window.open(sPath);
      }
    $('div:last div.active').qtip({
      content: 'This is an active div element',
      show: 'mouseover',
      hide: 'mouseout'
    })
</script>
```

Comment: In the IE8 debugger, what line does it show as being the source of the exception?  The only one I can imagine is the `window.open()` call, but I don't think a bogus URL would cause that error.

Comment: Maybe inside qtip ? I don't know this plugin.

Comment: There are some recent mentions of IE8 specific bug and fixes on the qtip forum. Do you have the last version ?

Comment: You included the qtip library after jQuery, right?

Comment: @ianpgall there's no error in Firefox, so I suppose it's yes.

Comment: @dystroy I wish I read that. Haha

Comment: The IE8 debugger should be able to point you to a line number, at least. Is it not?

Comment: sorry for the late response, IE8 is showing the line number. The code I posted above is from that line.

Comment: I'm going to update qtip to the latest version and see if that helps. It also doesn't happen in IE9. just IE8 as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like qTip uses a global variable named `tooltip` which may occasionally cause issues in IE8 (perhaps just in strict-mode).  Declaring `window.tooltip = null` at the top of my JS file that uses qTip resolved this issue for me, and more clearly indicates that the variable exists.